# Is the filestream in SQL Server backed up when using standard backup techniqe

Tags: sql-server-2014, backup, filestream

I'm using a SQL-Server 2014 database with filestream enabled. To backup this database I'm using the powershell command Backup-SqlDatabase, which is equivalent (as fas as I know) to T-SQL BACKUP DATABASE. The backup is stored in a "mydatabase.bak" file. My question is very simple: is the filestream backed up as well by this command or do I have to take further steps zu back it up?

Comment: Regardless of the answer, it does never hurt to actually try a restore at least once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backups include both filestream data and relational data. [Integrated management](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx) is one of the benefits of using filestream/filetable instead of storing files independently.

As suggested by the comments, practice recovery to ensure you can meet your RPO/RTO SLA objectives.